# How to handle state and database in Flutter Riverpod AsyncNotifier

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, riverpod, drift

In my app I have a **ListView** the shows some items. The list is **received from a local database** (sqlite/drift) and the according state is managed in an **Riverpod AsyncNotifierProvider**. The AsyncNotifierProvider uses an AsyncNotifier class which provides a method that **allows the user to reorder the items** in the list (change position).

**However my problem and question here is:**
I have to **manage the state** (Riverpod) as well as **the same information in the database** (cause the position of the items has to be persisted). Now **I´ve two options** how to handle this:

**1. Update the state and then update the database
2. Update the database and refresh the state from the database after the update**

*Option 1:*

```
/// Changes the order of the list items
Future<void> changeOrder(ListModel list, int oldIndex, int newIndex) async {
  
  // Change the position in the List<ListModel> which is stored in the state
  final previousState = state.valueOrNull;
  if (previousState != null) {
    final newState = [...previousState];
    if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
      newIndex -= 1;
    }
    final item = newState.removeAt(oldIndex);
    newState.insert(newIndex, item);
    state = AsyncValue.data(newState);
  }

  // Change the position in the database
  await _repo.changeOrder(list, oldIndex, newIndex);
}
```

*Option 2:*

```
/// Changes the order of the list items
Future<void> changeOrder(ListModel list, int oldIndex, int newIndex) async {

  // Change the position in the database
  await _repo.changeOrder(list, oldIndex, newIndex);

  // Fetch the new state from the database
  state = AsyncValue.data(await _repo.getAll());
}
```

Option 2 ensures that database and state are in sync but it needs more performacne (additional query to fetch the data) and I´m struggling with displaying the changes (cause the items jump back to the original position till the state from the database is refreshed -> leads to an ugly "flickering").

Which option is the way to go? Or is there another alternative I don´t know yet?

Comment: It's up to you.  The two versions are often called "optimistic update" and "pessimistic update", but they are both valid, and both have advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second option is preferable if the data is important to you. It provides a single source of truth. You might consider having the `changeOrder` query return the data (maybe this is possible in your case):

```dart
final newData = await _repo.changeOrder(list, oldIndex, newIndex);

state = AsyncValue.data(newData);
```

To keep the interface from flickering, consider using `ReorderableListView`.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView-class.html